# Understanding "For In" loop code

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm following a tutorial to learn swift and one of the apps is tic tac toe. The code uses lots of arrays and arrays within arrays, and it became confusing pretty quickly. I don't want to move on to the next tutorial until I'm confident in my understand of how this code is working. My questions about this code are as follows:

- How does `combo[]` know which space it is referring to when checking for a win?
- In `for combo in winCombos`, what is combo's function?
- How does `winCombos` work with `gameState` to tell if there is a winner?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var turnNumber = 1

    var winner = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!

    var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    let winCombos = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6]]

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if(gameState[sender.tag] == 0) {

            var oImage = UIImage(named: "Tic Tac Toe O.png")
            var xImage = UIImage(named: "Tic Tac Toe X.png")



            if(turnNumber%2 == 0) {

                sender.setImage(oImage, forState: .Normal)
                gameState[sender.tag] = 1
            }else{
                sender.setImage(xImage, forState: .Normal)
                gameState[sender.tag] = 2
            }

            for combo in winCombos {
                if(gameState[combo[0]] == gameState[combo[1]] && gameState[combo[1]] == gameState[combo[2]] && gameState[combo[0]] != 0) {

                    println(combo[0])
                    println(combo[1])
                    println(combo[2])

                    winner = gameState[combo[0]]
                }
            }

            if( winner != 0){
                println("Winner!")
            }

            turnNumber++

        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gameState` array is simply the cells of the Tic Tac Toe game, with indexes as follows:

```
 0 | 1 | 2
---+---+---
 3 | 4 | 5
---+---+---
 6 | 7 | 8
```

From that, it's easy to discern what `winCombo` is, it's the list of possible wins, such as `0,1,2` (top row) and `2,4,6` (bottom-left to top-right diagonal).

The statement:

```
for combo in winCombos
```

is just a loop, setting `combo` to each of the values in `winCombos` and using that to see if there's been a win.

So ther *first* time through the loop, `combo` is set to `[0,1,2]` and you can check if all those cells are non-zero *and* equal to each other - if so, you have a win.

Ditto for subsequent iterations of that loop, where `combo` takes on the subsequent values in the `winCombos` array.

Let's say you have a win on the final check `2,4,6` with all the values being `X` (2 in this case). The checking statement can be gradually narrowed down from:

```
if(gameState[combo[0]] == gameState[combo[1]] &&
   gameState[combo[1]] == gameState[combo[2]] &&
   gameState[combo[0]] != 0)
```

to:

```
if(gameState[2] == gameState[4] && gameState[4] == gameState[6] && gameState[2] != 0)
```

and, from there:

```
if(2 == 2 && 2 == 2 && 2 != 0)
```

to get your winner.